# JPA2 Annotation for Map<String, List<Entity>>

Tags: list, jpa, dictionary, entity

I am stuck with a proper mapping for this:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Map<String, List<Entity>> entitiesMap = new HashMap<String, List<Entity>>;
```

When I try to merge this I get:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.registerObjectForMergeCloneIntoWorkingCopy(MergeManager.java:1047)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.MergeManager.mergeChangesOfCloneIntoWorkingCopy(MergeManager.java:557)
```

I am able to persist the entities in the List. So the problem should not be there. Any ideas?

Comment: The construct is not currently supported. Only option is to transform to Map in memory.

Comment: You mean to say, the List inside the Map is not supported?
Can you give an example how to transform this? In the List I don't have keys, so how to I transform that into a Map for persistence?

Comment: You cannot. You need to map it as a collection Set, List etc. If you want to expose a Map to clients of this class you need to deal with constructing the Map yourself from the loaded collection.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input Alan. I have created now a value pair object (holding the key and the value) and put that into a List. The transformation to a Map is done now in the JsonSerializer. Seems that the transformation of JSON structures to JPA is not always that straight forward.